Is it safe to invoke php callback on multiple threads?
In my PHP-CPP extension, I use C++ threads to implement asynchronous workers that invoke passed PHP callbacks. Is it safe to run PHP callbacks in parallel as long as they are not using shared data?

I would avoid it if possible. What does the callback do?

I think a lot more context about a specific use case with some specific code would make the question a lot more likely to get an answer. See also [ask]


as long as they are not using shared data

Perhaps you are referring to global variables, but this is far from enough.
First, your PHP binary must be compiled with --enable-zts.
Next, you need to know that PHP's multithreading is not implemented through locks, but rather by allocating the memory that each thread can access individually. This implementation is essentially not much different from multiprocessing.
So if you want to call a user function on a new thread, you first need PHP to allocate individual memory for your thread, initialize the executor and extensions, and then you can run the user function.
There are already some PHP multithreading extensions to refer to, such as swoole, parallel
